# Strange behavior when appending array to matrix

Tags: go

I'm missing something fundamental about slices that's causes my result to end up looking strange.

Yes this is a question from leetcode. I was using it to learn go because I find that solving algorithms in new languages is helpful to me. I don't need the answer to the algorithm and I don't need to know how to fix the algorithm. I just want to know why my appended value changes when I append another value.

First off here's my code:

```
type node struct {
    value int
    children []*node
}

func combinationSum(candidates []int, target int) [][]int {
    
    var output [][]int
    
    var acc []int
    
    combinationSum2(candidates, &output, target, acc, 0)
    
    return output
}

func combinationSum2(candidates []int, output *[][]int, target int, acc []int, sum int) {
    
    if(sum == target) {
        fmt.Println(acc)
        *output = append(*output, acc)
        fmt.Println(output)
        return
    }
    
    if(sum > target) {
        return
    }
    
    for i := 0; i < len(candidates); i++ {
        combinationSum2(candidates[i:], output, target, append(acc, candidates[i]), sum + candidates[i])
    }
    
}
```

I was testing this code with candidates=[2,3,5] and target=8

the correct output should be [[2,2,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,5]]; however, my code returns [[2,2,2,5],[2,3,3],[3,5]]

interestingly, when I log about the acc values in the if statement and the output after appending the acc value, it seems the the value that I appended changes after appending the second array.

```
acc = [2 2 2 2]
output = &[[2 2 2 2]]

acc = [2 3 3]
output = &[[2 2 2 5] [2 3 3]]

acc = [3 5]
output = &[[2 2 2 5] [2 3 3] [3 5]]
```

I tried running this locally, and get the same strange behavior. What's causing this?

Comment: Read this article about [append](https://blog.allegro.tech/2017/07/golang-slices-gotcha.html) behavior. It is exactly what you encountered. 

TL;DR
Be careful when using append. Don’t append to slices you want to keep unchanged. If you want to work on a copy of a slice data, you must explicitly copy it into a new slice.

Comment: So you're saying that I can't use `append` the same way I would use ArrayList.add in java? What's the point of append if I can't reliably add elements to the same slice?

Comment: The equivalent of `ArrayList.add` will be `acc = append(acc, candidates[i])`.

Comment: okay, but then this should work as well `*output = append(*output, acc)`. I want to add an slice to a list of slices because the output is supposed to be a matrix.

However, there's a 5 where there should be 2 after I append a second slice. The third slice doesn't affect the second in the same way.

Comment: it is extrememly important that you spend time reading the blog posts, which in turns are smplfiied version of the specifications. Otherwise you will spend your ime hitting problems like this. Two ways are in front of you, 1/ learn it the hard way 2/ take the prepared way by the go team to make you succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i wrote in the comment the problem in original code is with append usage in `combinationSum2` function. The `append` was used to pass current `acc` extended by current `candidate` to `combinationSum2` method.
I've added more logging to this function

```
func combinationSum2(candidates []int, output *[][]int, target int, acc []int, sum int) {
    if sum == target {
        fmt.Println("Acc:", acc)
        *output = append(*output, acc)
        fmt.Println("Output:", output)
        return
    }

    if sum > target {
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(candidates); i++ {
        extendedAcc := append(acc, candidates[i])
        fmt.Printf("Extended: %v %p\n", extendedAcc, extendedAcc)
        combinationSum2(candidates[i:], output, target, extendedAcc, sum+candidates[i])
    }
}
```

and received following result (this is only few first interesting lines)

```
Extended: [2] 0x14000130008
Extended: [2 2] 0x14000130030
Extended: [2 2 2] 0x1400013c020
Extended: [2 2 2 2] 0x1400013c020
Acc: [2 2 2 2]
Output: &[[2 2 2 2]]
Extended: [2 2 2 3] 0x1400013c020
Extended: [2 2 2 5] 0x1400013c020
Extended: [2 2 3] 0x1400013c040
Extended: [2 2 3 3] 0x1400013c040
```

As you see the `extendedAcc` variable after it was added to `Output` still has the same address (they are printed as hex after the value). The final value for this address is `[2 2 2 5]` which is what you see in `Output`. The reason why it is not `[2 2 3 3]` is the result of how append works internally. In case when there is not enough space in current array it creates new one and returns a slice to it. And this behavior is visible when you compare the addresses of `extended` slice .

Here is properly working solution:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type node struct {
    value    int
    children []*node
}

func combinationSum(candidates []int, target int) [][]int {
    var output [][]int
    var acc []int
    combinationSum2(candidates, &output, target, acc, 0)
    return output
}

func combinationSum2(candidates []int, output *[][]int, target int, acc []int, sum int) {
    if sum == target {
        fmt.Println(acc)
        *output = append(*output, acc)
        fmt.Println(output)
        return
    }

    if sum > target {
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(candidates); i++ {
        currentAcc := make([]int, 0, len(acc) + 1)
        currentAcc = append(currentAcc, acc...)
        currentAcc = append(currentAcc, candidates[i])
        combinationSum2(candidates[i:], output, target, currentAcc, sum+candidates[i])
    }
}

func main() {
    combinationSum([]int{2, 3, 5}, 8)
}
```

Alternatively the `combinationSum2` function may look like this:

```
func combinationSum2(candidates []int, output *[][]int, target int, acc []int, sum int) {
    if sum == target {
        fmt.Println(acc)
        accCopy := make([]int, 0, len(acc))
        accCopy = append(accCopy, acc...)
        *output = append(*output, accCopy)
        fmt.Println(output)
        return
    }

    if sum > target {
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(candidates); i++ {
        combinationSum2(candidates[i:], output, target, append(acc, candidates[i]), sum+candidates[i])
    }
}
```

Which in my opinion is less safe in general but will work properly for this problem.

Comment: So I was populating output with references to the values in acc instead of the values of acc?

From what it looks like, you're created new arrays for each acc and populating output with each of its references, right? 

That's cool and not something I'm used to as a mostly Java/javascript dev.

Thanks.

Comment: Before and after changes it populates output with slice. The difference is that in your code this slice refers two the same array which is used by multiple for iteration, and in mine i create new array. [Here](https://blog.golang.org/slices) you find better explanation how slice and array differs.